# Can someone tell me the text in “navbar-right” is not in bold like the text in “navbar-left”

Tags: html, css, text, bold

When I run the HTML code the text under “navbar-left” it is perfect, but the text under “navbar-right” is not bold and does not look the same. I imported the proper font and I am just wonder what my mistake was. I would like all of the text in the navbar to look the same in terms of boldness and font.
Any help would be huge thank you!

```css
@import url(//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/d7e8a95865396cddca89b00080d2cba6?family=SoDo+Sans+SemiBold);

body {
   margin: 0px;
   font-family: "SoDo Sans SemiBold",Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: flex;
}

.navbar-right {
    justify-content: right;
    display: flex;
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: right;
}

h3 {
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

.navbar-left h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar-left,
.navbar-right {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.navbar-left > *,
.navbar-right > * {
    margin: 10px;
}

li {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="cleanstyle.css" />
      <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/d7e8a95865396cddca89b00080d2cba6?ifamily=SoDo+Sans+SemiBold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-left">
        <h3>Example</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-right">
        <div>Home</div>
        <div>About</div>
        <div>Portfolio</div>
        <div>Contact</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I couldn’t seem to locate the issue. Any help would be amazing - thank you.

Comment: Seems to work fine here other than the font takes awhile to load

Comment: You have the text in the left hand side within an h3 element. Use your browser's devtools  inspect facility to see the font weights that are being set by the browser.

Comment: They're all bold because of the font choice, but the h3 on the left is larger because h3 font is larger than div font by default. Why are you not using divs for all of them?